# How delete item without form with Ajax in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I would like delete a item whitout using a form using Ajax in Laravel 6
In my route I have

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard/desfazer-importe', 'DeleteImportController@index')->middleware('auth');
    Route::delete('/dashboard/desfazer-importe/{id}', 'DeleteImportController@destroy')->middleware('auth');
});
```

My view I have

```
div class="modal-body">    
     <h5>Deseja realmente desfazer esta importação?</h5>
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php $portal_id ?>" id="portal_id">  
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete" data-token="">Desfazer</button>
</div>
```

I'm getting id by input hidden

and in Ajax I have the following code

```
function deleteImport()
{
   $('#delete').click(function() {
   let porta_id = $('#portal_id').val() 
   $(this).prop("disabled",true);

   $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/dashboard/desfazer-importe',       
        data: {
            "id": porta_id,  
        }, 
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
      })
   })
 }
```

its possible delete item without to use form action ?
I get this message when I send

```
message: "CSRF token mismatch."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add csrf token into your request: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

And it looks like you have another problem. You have to add your item ID into url. `/dashboard/desfazer-importe/{id}`

Comment: So , I can't pass id in data : {id: 1} ?

Comment: your request link has to be `localhost/dashboard/desfazer-importe/123` ... because you have `Route::delete('/dashboard/desfazer-importe/{id}', 'DeleteImportController@destroy')->middleware('auth');`

Comment: I input url: "/dashboard/desfazer-importe/" + porta_id,
            data : {'_token': '{!! @csrf !!}'},

Comment: or I need to create <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in view ?

Comment: instead of @csrf (this return <input type="hidden" ......) you have to add csrf_token()